# Dynamic Columns from List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I need help to get the columns from list dyanmic using LINQ. Like this,

```
List<DashBoard> dashboardlist = (List<DashBoard>)objList;

objList = (from obj in dashboardlist 
          select new { obj.EprotexStatus, obj.RecReference, obj.RecDescription, 
                       obj.RecDate, obj.ModifiedDate, obj.RectypeDesc 
          }).ToList();
```

above is working fine to return columns from list using LINQ.

But I want specific columns from list in following process

```
List<DashBoard> dashboardlist = (List<DashBoard>)objList;
string strColumns = "RecDate,ModifiedDate";
objList = (from obj in dashboardlist 
           select new { strColumns }
          ).ToList();
```

Above statement i want get two columns only based on string columns variable.

Comment: You can't. `select  new { obj.EprotexStatus,...}` is an alternative syntax for `Enumerable.Select(dashboardList,obj=>new {...})`. That lambda is an an actual C# expression, not a string. You'd have to parse the list of columns and generate the same expression in code. There are some libraries that can do that

Comment: If you are expecting to do this with an anonymous type, then you're out of luck. Those are still actual C# classes that are generated by the compiler. You need to use a pre-made class that has all of the properties you may want to select, or look into using a Dictionary, tuple or some other hack. You can simplify this by using [DynamicLinq](https://dynamic-linq.net/)

Comment: i get strColumns values and based on that i need to get the results.Any other way i can try? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Did you try googling or searching SO? You'll find several similar questions. `Select` expects either a `Func<>` or an `Expression<Func<>>`. You'll have to construct one or the other. There are some libraries that can be used to do this, but quite often, if you already know the possible combinations it's easier to just create the relevant functions and pass them as parameters to `Select`, eg `if(someCondition==true){ query=query.Select(SelectFunc1);}` or `var selector = iif(someCondition)?SelectFunc1:SelectFunc2; ... query.Select(selector)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/1.2.15) package.

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

List<object> result = dashboardlist.Select("new {RecDate,ModifiedDate}").ToList();
```

Here's a stand alone sample that works in a plain console application (assuming .NET 6). First, create a console application. On the command line:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package System.Linq.Dynamic.Core
```

Then, replace `Program.cs` with this:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

var people = new[]
{
    new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", BirthDate = new DateTime(1970,1,1)},
    new Person { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Bar", BirthDate = new DateTime(1970,1,1)},
}.AsQueryable();

var query = people.Where("LastName = \"Doe\"").Select("new { FirstName, BirthDate }");

foreach (dynamic item in query)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName}'s birthdate is {item.BirthDate}");

internal class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, use `dotnet run` and see the result. It should output `John's birthdate is 1/01/1970 0:00:00`.

Comment: i tried to by importing the library but select is not taking from dynamic library.@jeroenh

Comment: I added a stand-alone sample to demonstrate. If you're still stuck, you'll have to update your question with more information to reproduce your issue.